# Time-independent Canonical transformation conditions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

A solution manual to Goldstein's  $9.1$ states that for an explicit time-independent transformation (for a system with two degrees of freedom) to be canonical it must satisfy

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial P},$$
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial p}=-\frac{\partial q}{\partial P},$$
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial q}=-\frac{\partial p}{\partial Q},$$
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial q}{\partial Q},$$

however, I do not seem to be able to see where this is coming from.

Comment: Hint: Combine Cramer's rule & Liouville's theorem.

Comment: @Qmechanic The current knowledge that I have at the moment is that Liouville's theorem states that the the "volume" of a system remains unchanged with regard to canonical transformations. However, that is all that I currently know. I am assuming that there must be a way to represent this in matrix form? Is there perhaps a more elementary way to arrive at the equations above?

Comment: How does the book define canonical transformations? According to some of the various equivalent definitions, the statement is almost a tautology.

Comment: One definition is that $JSJ^t=S$, where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix of the transformation $(q,p)\to (Q,P)$ and $S$ is the matrix with $0,0$ on the principal diagonal and $1,-1$ on the other disgonal. It satisfies $SS=-I$. With this definition you have $J= -SJ^{t-1}S$. This is your identity.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Currently reading Goldstein and Landau, Landau's condition is that $\left[Q_{i}, Q_{k}\right]_{p, q}=0, \quad\left[P_{i}, P_{k}\right]_{p, q}=0, \quad\left[P_{i}, Q_{k}\right]_{p, q}=\delta_{i k}$, where the subscripts denote with respect to what the partial derivatives are taken. Goldstein's book mentions the symplectic condition which you have provided, will look at that now to see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: These two conditions are in fact equivalent.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thanks, I see how they are now!